# NoSQL with inheritance support for .NET

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, object-oriented-database, nosql

Are there any NoSQL DBs that support object inheritance in .NET out of the box? MongoDB has something which is proper for dynamic languages but I'm looking for real inheritance. Actually I think I should work on an ODBMS instead of NoSQL!? Or does MongoDB support strongly-typed inheritance?

I would like to get data using such queries in LINQ:

```
people.Where(p => p is Student)
```

Comment: You'd need to add a type field to each document in MongoDB to get similar behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB C# driver supports `OfType` and `is` in LINQ queries!

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-linq-tutorial

Comment: Last time I played with MongoDB the linq extensions were not that great -- that looks cool!

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB has something similar to what you want to do.

http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/polymorphism

Comment: I'm looking for something free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Starcounter uses the regular classes you program to store in the database, so you need no separate database definition. The database and the application are married together so all objects you query/work with are the actual .NET objects. Still true ACID.

You query the database using regular SQL92 expressions (Linq is to slow) like this: Db.SQL("SELECT s FROM MyClass WHERE ...") and the returned enumerator contains your .NET objects.